# How to pass a value from component class to a function existing outside the class in angular

Tags: angular

I need to pass a value of a variable from component class to a function outside the class.I am not able to achieve.Below is my code and on clicking the button the error I am getting is *"cannot read property divide of undefined"*.
Please help me with the solution.

**App component.ts**

```
import {Component NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {GameButtonsComponent} from './buttons/game-buttons.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ' blblb'
})
export class AppComponent {

divide:number=5;

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){}

calc()

}

function calc()
{
 return 100/this.divide
}
```

**html**

```
<button (click)="calc()"></button>
```

Comment: That is not how OOP works. Could you please clarify what is the purpose of such a method?

Comment: @michael I had to implement a valuegetter functionality in ag grid where similar kind of task needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in app.component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public divide = 3;
  public calc() {
    alert(calculate(this.divide));
  }
}
calculate = (divide) => 100/divide;
```

**OR**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public divide = 3;
  public calc() {
    calculate.call(this);
  }
}
calculate = function(){return 100/this.divide};
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do within the component itself rather than exporting.One way is using sessionstorage but am looking for other options

Comment: I just surprised to see `calculate(this.divide)` works?!

Comment: yes because we use call and in javascript call can change the reference of this for any method.

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this in your component....

```
calc = calc.bind(this)
```

but what you're trying to do here is very suspect.

Answer (score 0):

you do not require to provide function keyword for defining a function. Try this code below

```
ngOnInit(){}

this.calc()

}

calc()
{
 return 100/this.divide
}
```

**Alternate Way**
declare a new variable using let or const keyword inside the parent function block and assign a new

```
ngOninit() {
const myVal = this.something;
this.calc(myVal)
}

calc(val)
{
 return 100/val;
}
```